# Modifying The Preloader To Output A Different Letter

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

I have the following preloader code:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #21252B;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr)); */
}

.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #89C9B8;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 3s linear infinite;
}

svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #89C9B8;
}

/* .svg-file h2 span:nth-child(1) {
    animation: fadein-fadeout 1s infinite;
} */

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: #89C9B8;
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

/* .svg-file h2 span:nth-last-child(1) {
    animation: fadein-fadeout 2s infinite;
} */

@keyframes dots {

    0%,
    20% {
        background-color: rgb(191, 224, 215, .08);
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08),
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    40% {
        background-color: #89C9B8;
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08),
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    60% {
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 #89C9B8,
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 #89C9B8,
            .5em 0 0 #89C9B8;
    }
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}

/* @keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    40% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    60% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }
} */
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="svg-file z-logo">
            <svg width="133" height="119" viewBox="-1 -5 150 119" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M37.5 7.5L26.25 41.25L71.6667 37.5L0 118.75L100.417 112.083L113.75 75L82.5 76.6667L132.083 0L37.5 7.5Z"
                    fill="#47AF9A" />
            </svg>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So I basically want the output to be `H` instead of `Z` it currently displays. I tried changing the measurements in the `CSS` file but I would totally get a different output, and I basically want to make it so it outputs the letter `H` instead of `Z`

I also tried changing this code in the css:

```
@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
```

Since this is the animation of the whole preloader, and it controls how the animation works for the particular `z` preloader, I tried changing some of the classes up with different measurements to see a different output than `z` so that I will get a better idea on how to better make it output `h` but I am currently stuck on that part, and would require additional help on which classes I should adjust the measurements/code of. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in SVG code like below:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #21252B;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr)); */
}

.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #89C9B8;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 695;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 3s linear infinite;
}

svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #89C9B8;
}

/* .svg-file h2 span:nth-child(1) {
    animation: fadein-fadeout 1s infinite;
} */

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: #89C9B8;
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

/* .svg-file h2 span:nth-last-child(1) {
    animation: fadein-fadeout 2s infinite;
} */

@keyframes dots {

    0%,
    20% {
        background-color: rgb(191, 224, 215, .08);
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08),
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    40% {
        background-color: #89C9B8;
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08),
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    60% {
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 #89C9B8,
            .5em 0 0 rgba(191, 224, 215, .08);
    }

    80%,
    100% {
        box-shadow:
            .25em 0 0 #89C9B8,
            .5em 0 0 #89C9B8;
    }
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}

/* @keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    40% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    60% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-width: 0;
        fill: #89C9B8;
    }
} */
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="svg-file z-logo">            
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133"><g id="H"><path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z" fill="#47AF9A"/></g></svg>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```